# How can I combine event function and command function include ctx?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
@bot.command()
async def PrivateChannel(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    }
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel('secret', overwrites=overwrites)
```

this is the code that makes a private channel

I want to make a private channel when user comes into the voice channel

So I had to put this function in @bot.event

but It doesn't work.

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        async def PrivateChannel(ctx):
            guild = ctx.guild
            overwrites = {
                guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            }
            channel = await guild.create_text_channel('secret', overwrites=overwrites)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because you need to pass an invocation context  (in this case `ctx`) to the command coroutine, which you cannot get from the `on_voice_state_update` event.

Since you only need `ctx` to get `guild`, you can use [`member.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.guild) instead of `ctx.guild`.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        guild = member.guild
        overwrites = {
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            }
        channel = await guild.create_text_channel('secret', overwrites=overwrites)
```